# Build table using partial view with Ajax requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, insert, partial-views, tablerow

I need to dynamically create (insert) a new table row every time user presses button (using Ajax). My partial view structure:

```
    <tr>
         <td><td>
         <td><td>
         ...
    </tr>
```

When I need insert new row at the end I can do something like this:

```
    element_table.innerHTML += ajax_data
```

But what I must do when I need to place it between other rows?

I can return only [td] elements and wrap them in [tr] clientside created element (tr.innerHTML = ajax_data) but I don't think this is a good idea.

Any ideas?

Are there any common practises?

Comment: would you be willing to rebuild the entire table? In other words, when there's a change, call a partial that rebuilds the table along with your new td?

Comment: I dont think about it.In my case I can do this.But what if the table is big?Then new rows must inserted with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use jQuery with your Ajax response. It can be as simple as

```
$('#table').append(response)
```

[to append a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery). It's also possible to [insert the new row at a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577860/jquery-insert-new-row-into-table-at-a-certain-index):

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr').eq(index).after(response);
```

Note that index is 0 based.